# Autotools detect C++ language standard support

Tags: c++, macros, m4

I have been updating my build tools to optionally use autotools (autoconfig/automake/libtool etc.).

As part of this change I have written a couple of M4 macros. This not being something I have done before. Any input is appreciated on style or if things can be done better.

A macro for detecting what version of C++ is available and defining the correct flags:

```
AC_DEFUN(
    [AX_FUNC_THOR_LANG_FLAG],
    [
        minLangFeature=$1
        AS_IF([test "$2" = ""], [maxLangFeature=17], [maxLangFeature=$2])
        AS_IF([test $minLangFeature -gt $maxLangFeature], AC_MSG_ERROR([Invalid Language Value],[1]))

        AC_LANG(C++)
        CXXMaxLanguage=03
        CXXExpLanguage=03
        AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++11], [AC_SUBST([CXXMaxLanguage],11) AC_SUBST([StdFlag11],[-std=c++11])])
        AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++14], [AC_SUBST([CXXMaxLanguage],14) AC_SUBST([StdFlag14],[-std=c++14])])
        AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++17], [AC_SUBST([CXXMaxLanguage],17) AC_SUBST([StdFlag17],[-std=c++17])])
        AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++1x], [AC_SUBST([CXXExpLanguage],11) AC_SUBST([ExpFlag11],[-std=c++1x])])
        AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++1y], [AC_SUBST([CXXExpLanguage],14) AC_SUBST([ExpFlag14],[-std=c++1y])])
        AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++1z], [AC_SUBST([CXXExpLanguage],17) AC_SUBST([ExpFlag17],[-std=c++1z])])

        #CXX_STD_FLAG
        #CXXSTDVER

        AS_IF(
            [test $minLangFeature -le $CXXMaxLanguage],
            [
                AS_IF(
                    [test $maxLangFeature -le $CXXMaxLanguage],
                    [AC_SUBST([CXXSTDVER], [$maxLangFeature])],
                    [AC_SUBST([CXXSTDVER], [$CXXMaxLanguage])]
                )
                AC_SUBST([CXX_STD_FLAG], [$(eval echo "\${StdFlag${CXXSTDVER}}")])
                ],
                [AS_IF(
                    [test $minLangFeature -le $CXXExpLanguage],
                    [
                        AS_IF(
                            [test $maxLangFeature -le $CXXExpLanguage],
                            [AC_SUBST([CXXSTDVER], [$maxLangFeature])],
                            [AC_SUBST([CXXSTDVER], [$CXXExpLanguage])]
                        )
                        AC_SUBST([CXX_STD_FLAG], [$(eval echo "\${ExpFlag${CXXSTDVER}}")])
                ],
                [AC_MSG_ERROR([

Error: Need C++${minLangFeature} but the compiler only supports ${CXXMaxLanguage} (Experimental ${CXXExpLanguage})

                    ], [1])]
            )]
        )
    ]
)
```

Usage:

```
AX_FUNC_THOR_LANG_FLAG(<min acceptable C++> [, <max acceptable C++>])
```

If you don't specify a max then `17` is used as the default. It works out what flags are available to modify the behavior of the C++ compiler to a different version of the standard and then defines the two macros:

```
CXXSTDVER      /* Will hold 03 11 14 or 17 */
CXX_STD_FLAG   /* Will hold the flag needed be the C++ compiler */
```

It considers `-std=c++1[147]` as standard version and will use these if they satisfy the minimum requirements. It considers `-std=c++1[xyz]` as experimental versions and will only use these if the minimum requirements cannot be achieved by using the standard version flags.

Comment: @Toby Speight I already made it part of my libraries. See: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorMaker with a couple of other autotools macros here https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorMaker/blob/master/autotools/m4/thorbuildinit.m4 Examples of how to use it here https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/configure.ac Example of how to use the makefile ThorMaker here https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/src/Serialize/Makefile

Comment: GNU autoconf provides a set of macros for setting the standard, e.g.
https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_17.html#ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_17
isn't it better?

Comment: @MariusM Yes standard macros are always better. I will look to include them.

Comment: Is this macro doing similar thing? AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX(17, [noext], [mandatory])

Comment: @camp0 thanks will check it out.

Comment: You can check here @MartinYork just in case https://bitbucket.org/camp0/aiengine/src/master/configure.ac